# Not able to locate webelement

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, xpath

I am not able locate  a webelement, this web application opens in Internet explorer only and I have used all the possible ways to click but no luck.
Xpath locators that I have tried :

```
"//form[@id='Form1']//a[contains(text(),'Age Range')]"
```

and

```
"//form[@id='Form1']//a[@id='rptTables1_ctl07_hlTablename1']"
```

also I have tried click on the element using action class and javascript as well.

Attached DOM in the URL, please have a look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5igHd.png)

Comment: Hi @Amit Vishnu Sharma, are you able to locate an element using the locators that you have mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

In the node `a`, `id` value is not static so you can't locate that element using the `id` value but you can use partial `id` value for example, looks like `rptTables1_` is unique in id value and the remaining part is changing so applying `contains()` on this may works.

Try the below xpath if there is only match :

```
//a[contains(@id, 'rptTables1_')]
```

Try the below xpath by providing the matching index if there are multiple xpath matches :

```
(//a[contains(@id, 'rptTables1_')])[Matching index number]
```

for example if the matching index is `3` then you can write like this `(//a[contains(@id, 'rptTables1_')])[3]`.

Or you can use the `Advanced Performance Parameters Panel Topics` text to identify that element.

```
//a[contains(text(), 'Advanced Performance Parameters Panel Topics')]
```

Again if there are multiple matches then try to use indexing method as mentioned above.

Or you can try the below modified your xpaths :

```
//form[@id='Form1']//a[contains(@id, 'rptTables1_')]
```

or

```
(//form[@id='Form1']//a[contains(@id, 'rptTables1_')])[Matching index number]
```

or

```
//form[@id='Form1']//a[contains(text(), 'Advanced Performance Parameters Panel Topics')]
```

I hope it helps...

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried any automation in IE  at all but in firefox, sometimes I encounter those issues and my work around other than the .click() function is send_keys(Keys.RETURN). Also, i'm using time.sleep(x) before clicking or sending keys to make sure the element has been loaded.

Comment: Thankyou Wrath I have tried your way but not working , actually i am not even able to locate that webelement "InvalidSelector The xpath expressoin" i am getting , i have attached link of DOM screenshot, have a look. also i have used thread.sleep(2000) just to give some time but not working.